# Google translate tool not working

Tags: php, internet-explorer, google-translate

I am new to website designing and i used this google translate tool script as given the the wesite:
http://translate.google.com/translate_tools
Initially it was working fine on internet explorer but when i added class="no translate" to two drop down lists then the translate button seems no to be not working on IE(internet explorer) though its working fine on google chrome..
The problem coming on internet explorer is: as i select a language from the google translate drop down lists then shows the message that translation in progress 0% ..
However nothing happens and it gets stuck on the same page, no translation is done and the same message is shown.

Can anybody help me please??

Comment: You should be warned that Google is shutting down their free translate API and instead creating a service you have to pay for. I don't know how that may effect your plans.

Comment: @pthurmond for the mean time this wont effect my site.. can you please help me finding out how to solve this problem..??

Comment: I apologize, I was tired last night when I wrote that and I misunderstood what you are doing. Their JavaScript tool is still free. My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @pthurmond.. no problem at all...Its ok. can you tell me how to deal with the problem, i am facing..??

Answer (score 1):

The class is `notranslate` (as opposed to your `no translate`):

```
<div class="notranslate">
...
</div>
```

[Source](http://www.seroundtable.com/archives/020684.html)

Comment: thanks for your reply @esqew.. Actually by mistake i entered space between notranslate but i am using class="notranslate" on my webpage and its even working as well on the browsers: chrome and safari but its not working on IE(internet explorer).. before adding this tag the google translation was working but after adding this .. google translation is no longer working on IE and as i have said in my question that it gets stuck when translating the page saying: 'translation in progress 0%' .. so can you help me that how can i make this working... ??